# Uploading multiple images from android Sd to PHP backend

Tags: php, android, multiprocessing

i used: httmine 4.1 jar upload many images my code:

```
private void postFile() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[type]);


    Bitmap pic1 = ImageFile.decodeFile(currentPath, 180);
    currentPath=ConstValue.MY_TEMP_DIR + "/search.jpg";
    ImageFile.writePhotoJpg(pic1, currentPath);
    File file = new File(currentPath);
//  File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/aaaa.txt");


    FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    //FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    try {
         mpEntity.addPart("fileToUpload", cbFile);
        //mpEntity.addPart( "fileToUpload",new FileBody(file));

        mpEntity.addPart("sys", new StringBody("android"));
        mpEntity.addPart("sex", new StringBody(sex));
        mpEntity.addPart("ver", new StringBody(ConstValue.VERSION_NAME));
        mpEntity.addPart("uid", new StringBody(ConstValue.UID));
        mpEntity.addPart("page", new StringBody("1"));
        mpEntity.addPart("offset", new StringBody("30"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    //Log.d("log", httppost.getRequestLine().toString());
    //Log.d("Log", httppost.getEntity().toString());
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("log","111111111111111");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("log","2222222222222");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("log","33333333333");
    }
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


    if (resEntity != null) {
        try {
            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.i("log",""+response_str);
            if (!response_str.contains("@@@@")) {
                ConstValue.COUPLE_MATCH_RESAULT = ApplyXmlUtil.parseMastersXML(response_str);
            } else {

                errerCode=0;
            }

            // Log.d("log", response_str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{

    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

       my php code:


  $tmp_name = md5($uid.time().rand(0,20).microtime()).".jpg";
  $tmp_path = WWW_DIR.'/upload/tmp/andriodimg/'.$tmp_name;  
  $tmp_path2 = WWW_DIR.'/upload/tmp/andriodimg/'.$tmp_name.'_2.jpg';    
  $MAX_SIZE =4000000; //1M
  $FILE_MIMES = array('image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg');
   $xmlstr ='';

if (!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] != 'none') {
if(!in_array($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'],$FILE_MIMES)){
    $xmlstr='<code>2</code>';
    $xmlstr = "<".'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'."?>\r\n<body>\r\n".$xmlstr."</body>";
    @header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $xmlstr;

    exit;

    }
 if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > $MAX_SIZE){
    $xmlstr='<code>6</code>';
    $xmlstr = "<".'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'."?>\r\n<body>\r\n".$xmlstr."</body>";
    @header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $xmlstr;

    exit;
    }
$data = @file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
if(empty($data)){
    $xmlstr='<code>3</code>';
    $xmlstr = "<".'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'."?>\r\n<body>\r\n".$xmlstr."</body>";
    @header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $xmlstr;

    exit;
    }
file_put_contents($tmp_path, $data);
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($tmp_path);
if($type!=2){
    $xmlstr='<code>2</code>';
    $xmlstr = "<".'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'."?>\r\n<body>\r\n".$xmlstr."</body>";
    @header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $xmlstr;

    exit;

    }
if($height/$width > 5){
    @unlink($tmp_path);
    $xmlstr='<code>5</code>';
    $xmlstr = "<".'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'."?>\r\n<body>\r\n".$xmlstr."</body>";
    @header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    echo $xmlstr;

    exit;
    }

    $xmlstr .='<imgurl1>'.$website_default.$webdir."upload/tmp/andriodimg/".$tmp_name.'</imgurl1>';
}
```

sometime code is well,sometime cannot upload code,can you give me some advice help me find mistake